# two dimensional array to csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to export my python array to `csv` file using python. However, I could not make it, anyone help me please? My sample data and code are shown bellow:

array:

```
[[311.11324435763891, 459.35657654562112], [326.9993929036458, 488.02189410927855], [323.19149534625774, 455.74575749903551]]
```

I would like to generate a csv file like that:

> {empty} met1 met2 met3
>
> seq1 311.11324435763891 326.9993929036458 323.19149534625774
>
> seq2 459.35657654562112 488.02189410927855 455.74575749903551

my draft code is:

```
def writeCSVFile(outputfile,name_list):
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = [' ' 'm1','m2','m3']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        
        for x in name_list:
            writer.writerow({fieldnames[x]: )
```

Comment: It really helps having a `dictionary` when trying to use the `Dictwriter`. So you can go two ways, either convert your data to a dict structure and try again or just write them manually.

Comment: is `name_list` the 2 dimensional array/list ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy using the `pandas` then this will work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[311.11324435763891, 459.35657654562112], [326.9993929036458, 488.02189410927855], [323.19149534625774, 455.74575749903551]]).T

df.columns = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3']
df.index = ['seq1', 'seq2']
df.to_csv("output.csv", )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a beautiful solution but can generically solve the problem.

```
def write_csv_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        data = list(zip(*data))
        head = ["{empty}"] + ["met{0}".format(i+1) for i in range(len(data[0]))]
        f.write(' '.join(head)+'\n')
        for n, i in enumerate(data):
            line  =["seq{0}".format(n+1)]+[str(x) for x in i]
            f.write(' '.join(line)+'\n')
```

**Output**

```
{empty} met1 met2 met3
seq1 311.1132443576389 326.9993929036458 323.19149534625774
seq2 459.3565765456211 488.02189410927855 455.7457574990355
```

Comment: The ideal thing is to use the `csv` module from Python's standard library to write CSV files.  Also, Python allows one to use 8 spaces for identing -but "the World" realluy uses 4, some places use 2.

Comment: Sometimes you just need clear some data and move on , and if the first solution  that appears solves the problem, it's good enough. But I understand your point.